# How to persist the anchor status (focus) of a navigation menu item after LightBox gallery is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, persistence, lightbox2

I am developing a website that uses a dynamically populated navigation menu. Each menu item  has a unique ID when it is created. OnClick it calls the function populate_thumbs which fills a 3X3 grid of thumbnails to the left of the navigation menu. Also, once clicked the menu item is set to "focus" through CSS. When the user clicks on a thumbnail, a LightBox gallery overlays on top of the website.

The problem occurs when the user clicks outside the LightBox to dismiss it, that action takes the focus away from the menu item and it appears like the other menu items (i.e. don't know which project I was just looking at). How can I persist the status of the current menu item and return it to "focus" when LightBox is dismissed? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Javascript:

```
function init_projects(delayTime) {
$('#nav-container').delay(delayTime).fadeToggle(0);
$('#thumb-container').delay(delayTime).fadeToggle(0);
$.get('Content/projects.xml', function(d) {
    $(d).find('project').each(function () {
        var $project = $(this);
        var id = $project.attr("id");
        var name = $project.attr("name");
        var school = $project.attr("school");
        var html = '<div class="nav-menu-item" id="' + id + '" onclick="populate_thumbs(this.id);"><a href="#"><p>' + name + '<br />' + school + '</p></a></div>';
        $('#nav-menu-container').append($(html));
    });
})
ProjectsInitialized = true;}

function populate_thumbs(id) {
$('.thumb-holder').empty();
$.get('Content/projects.xml', function (d) {
    $(d).find("project[id=" + id + "]").children().each(function (c) {
        var $url = $(this);
        var projectName = $url.parent().attr("name") + " - " + $url.parent().attr("school");
        //store thumbnail and quadrant locations
        var thumb = $url.attr("thumb");
        var quad = $url.attr("quadrant");
        var image = $url.attr("image");
        var html = '<a href="' + image + '" rel="lightbox[gallery]" data-lightbox="' + projectName + '" data-title="' + projectName + '"><img onmousedown="return false;" src="' + thumb + '"/></a>';
        $('#quad-' + quad).append(html);
    })
});
currNavItem = id;}
```

CSS:

.nav-menu-item a:focus {color: yellow; border: .5px solid black; background: black;}